# Как кастомизировать whb в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Нужно исправить верстку хедера. На сайте используется woodmart header builder, но я не нашел в файлах, как я могу что-то поправить, скажите, возможно ли кастомизировать такие хедеры? нашел единственную строчку кода whb_generate_header(), а как поправить верстку через файлы так и не понял. Буду рад, если вы мне поможете.

Comment: В настройках плагина есть визуальный редактор.

Comment: Я понимаю, но привык всё делать вручную через файлы, это невозможно?

Comment: Наверняка возможно. В плагине должны быть хуки, которые надо использовать. Или шаблоны, которые можно перекрыть в своем плагине или дочерней теме. Править сам плагин - последнее дело.

Покажите, что конкретно вам нужно исправить и, возможно, вам приведут ответ с примером кода.

Comment: В шаблонах и style.css дочерней темы.